# dart - "There is no such getter 'function' in" issues

Tags: dart

I'm starting learning dart, I've installed the Dart Editor normally on a Linux system, but the problem comes up when I start to code a simple snippet of code for instance this:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector('#status').innerHtml = "Hola mundo";


  var button = new  ButtonElement();
  button.text = "Haz click";
  button.on.click.add( (e){

    var div = new Element.html("<div>puto</div>");

    document.body.elements.add(div);
  });

  document.body.elements.add(button);


}
```

I get three warnings with the same messages: "There is no such getter 'function' in..." in three different parts of the code:[image: warnings]

I got this code in a book, so the code is correct, How do I resolve this problem? thanks

**edit**: I cannot run this code with these warnings as you could expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is probably out of date from the current library APIs.

Try changing `elements` to `children`, e.g. `document.body.children.add(elem2);` is an example in the [DOM section of Dart: Up and Running](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-manipulating-the-dom).

Answer (score 2):

See the api

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-html.Element@id_onClick

```
ElementStream<MouseEvent> get onClick
Stream of click events handled by this Element.
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is outdated

```dart
// button.on.click.add( (e){
button.onClick.listen(callback);
// or button.on['my-custom-event'].litsen();
```